# ZFS on Home Computer as Debian Stretch Root

Tags: linux, hard-drive, grub, zfs, stretch

I'm going to build new computer in near future. I want to use ZFS on two 2TB HDDs in mirror for debian root and storage because of transparent compression, snapshots, ram/ssd caching and other cool features. Later I will add ssd as cache.

Is it good to use gzip-9 on dataset for root and lz4 on dataset for homes?
Are there any problems with placing Steam Library on zfs?
Are there any problems with booting using grub? I know from articles that it is necessary to turn off some features because grub don't support them yet. But articles aren't new. Something may change.

P.S. English isn't my native language.

Comment: GZip is *slow*. Only use it when you know what you’re doing. You don’t. Try stuff out! (Re-)Installing Debian is quickly done. You can (and should!) always use a separate `/boot` partition. Also, please read up on L2ARC and whatnot. Even on an SSD, the cache is not persistent across reboots.

Comment: I'd also recommend using separate disks for data and operating system if possible.  The separation makes life easy - data is important and can't be easily replaced while the operating system is replaceable. Even applications can be reinstalled,  It's your *data* that's important.  The operating system is really a throw-away installation and doesn't require anywhere near the level of protection your data does.